# Check if a users roles got changes in GuildMemberUpdated C# discord.net

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

So ive tryed stuff like 1-2 Days now and i dont know how to check if a role of a user got changed or not : / any idea?

~ Im learning discord.net rn : /

Many things from google and youtube but nothing worked.
I want to check if a user roles got changed and if yes i want to do something and if not i want to return.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really need to know the state of the user's roles before they were changed then you can do this with gateway intents and events.

Look into the discord events https://discordnet.dev/guides/concepts/events.html.
You might need to add an additional gateway intent to get the events from discord. The one you probably want is GuildMembers, see the code below on how to combine it with other intents.

```cs
var clientConfig = new DiscordSocketConfig { MessageCacheSize = 100, LogLevel = LogSeverity.Info, GatewayIntents = GatewayIntents.GuildMessages | GatewayIntents.Guilds | GatewayIntents.GuildMembers };
```

Then after your bot is logged in add the event to the client:

```cs
public static async Task Main()
{
    var clientConfig = new DiscordSocketConfig { MessageCacheSize = 100, LogLevel = LogSeverity.Info, GatewayIntents = GatewayIntents.GuildMessages | GatewayIntents.Guilds | GatewayIntents.GuildMembers };
    var client = new DiscordSocketClient(clientConfig);
    await client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, GetToken()).ConfigureAwait(false);

    client.GuildMemberUpdated += Client_GuildMemberUpdated;
}

private static async Task Client_GuildMemberUpdated(Cacheable<SocketGuildUser, ulong> cachedUser, SocketGuildUser postUpdateUser)
{
    if (cachedUser.HasValue)
    {
        if (cachedUser.Value.Roles.Count != postUpdateUser.Roles.Count)
        {
            // Roles of the user has changed
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to see what the value was before you most likely will need to know the previous state of the user ahead of time. The Discord API mostly just sends the current state of the user, and there's not really a way to get the old data. If you look over [this page](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway-events#guild-member-update) it tells you all the payloads you can get from discord as an event. guild-member-update seems like the closest to what you're looking for.